# why this CMake don´t compile?

Tags: c, linux, cmake, makefile

I'm stuck in a CMake project that isn't compiled. I isolated the problem in a simple test project. It is composed from a file `teste` (main) and a lib that is in `libs/` subdirectory. The teste is very simple: the main calls a function that is in lib.
The compiler is generating `.c.o` compiled files instead of `.o` files.  CMake generates the Makefile but when I run make it compiles ok but on link phase it gives me:

```
make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target testecompila
[ 50%] Linking C executable bin/testecompila
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/testecompila.dir/teste.c.o: na função "main":   <=== .c.o file
teste.c:(.text+0x19): referência não definida para "testeint" <=== the libs fct I call in main
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testecompila.dir/build.make:97: bin/testecompila] Erro 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/testecompila.dir/all] Erro 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Erro 2
```

Directory tree:

```
.    ===> testcompila dir
├── libs
│   ├── bin 
│   │    └── Makefile       ==>>> Generated from CMake
│   ├── include
│   │   └── testelib.h
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── testelib.c
└── src
    ├── bin 
    │    └── Makefile       ==>>> Generated from CMake
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── teste.c
```

test.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "testelib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return testeint();
}
```

testelib.h:

```
int testeint();
```

testelib.c:

```
#include "testelib.h"

int testeint()
{
  int C = 0;
  C++;
  return C;
}
```

teste.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "testelib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return testeint();
}
```

CMakeLists from ./src

```
####################
#      Global      #
####################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#####################
#      Project      #
#####################

# Project variables
set(LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME        "testecompila")
set(LOCAL_PROJECT_VERSION     "0.0.1")
set(LOCAL_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION "Teste compilação")

# Source files (relative to "src" directory)

set(SOURCES
    teste.c
   )

# Compiler definitions
set(DEFINES
)

# Compiler options
set(OPTIONS
)

# Project setup
project(${LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME}
        VERSION ${LOCAL_PROJECT_VERSION}
        DESCRIPTION ${LOCAL_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}
        LANGUAGES C)


add_executable(${LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME} teste.c)

list(TRANSFORM HEADERS PREPEND "../include/")
list(TRANSFORM SOURCES PREPEND "../src/")


INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../libs/include/)

message ("======>" ${LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME})

set_target_properties(${LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "bin")
set_target_properties(testecompila PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

target_include_directories(testecompila PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

####################
#   Dependencies   #
####################
```

CMakeLists.txt from ./libs/src

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)    

project(libteste)

add_library(libteste STATIC testelib.c)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(testelib.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/include )

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS --verbose)
```

I am on a VM Oracle VirtualBox runing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `testecompila` that is uses `libteste`. Try something like `target_link_libraries(${LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC libtests)`.

Comment: Thank you Lindydancer.  CMake is complainig that no sources for target PUBLIC. Is this PUBLIC correct? I tried removing it and then CMake complain about "cannot specify link library for target libtest wich is not build by this project"

Comment: I guess this is because `LOCAL_PROJECT_NAME` might be empty where you wrote the line, so that PUBLIC became the first argument. It should be in the CMakeLists.txt file in src. Also, that file must have included the one that defined libtests.